# Facing OP_GET_MORE does not support cursors with a write concern

Tags: mongodb, go

I am working on a GO application which uses MongoDB database through a driver.

Driver link: [Mongo Driver](https://pkg.go.dev/gopkg.in/mgo.v2)

I have setup 3 replicas on mongodb. My Replica-Set includes of Primary-Secondary-Secondary. I have set Mongodb default write concerns using the below command on primary

```
db.adminCommand({  setDefaultRWConcern: 1,  defaultReadConcern: { level : "majority" },  defaultWriteConcern: { w: "majority" }})
```

I'm making connection with mongodb using the following code:-

```
mongoDBDialInfo := &mgo.DialInfo{

    Addrs:     []string{ipPort,sec1IpPort,sec2IpPort},
    Username:  "username",
    Password:  "pwd",
    Database:  "admin",
    Timeout:   60 * time.Second,
    PoolLimit: 4096,
    ReplicaSetName:"repldb",
           
}
mongoSession, err := mgo.DialWithInfo(mongoDBDialInfo)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Printf("CreateSession: %s\n", err)
    defer mongoSession.Close()
    return mongoSession
}
mongoSession.SetSafe(&mgo.Safe{WMode: "majority"})
mongoSession.SetMode(mgo.Monotonic, true)
mongoSession.SetMode(mgo.SecondaryPreferred, true)
```

While executing the following query with the above settings. I'm facing an error i.e

> OP_GET_MORE does not support cursors with a write concern other than the default. Use the getMore command instead. Write concern was: { w: "majority", wtimeout: 0, provenance: "customDefault" }

```
mongoSession := MerchantDb.MongoSession

sessionCopy := mongoSession.Copy()
defer sessionCopy.Close()

getCollection := sessionCopy.DB(MerchantDb.Database).C(config.BookingsCollection)
pipe := getCollection.Pipe([]bson.M{
    {"$lookup": bson.M{
        "localField":   "uid",
        "from":         config.UsersCollection,
        "foreignField": "_id",
        "as":           "customer_info"}},
    {"$unwind": "$customer_info"},
    {"$lookup": bson.M{
        "localField":   "provider_ids",
        "from":         config.UsersCollection,
        "foreignField": "_id",
        "as":           "provider_info"}},
    {"$project": bson.M{
        "_id":                             1,
        "uid":                             1,
        "status":                          1,
        "booking_priority":                1,
        "is_waiting_list":                 1,
        "provider_ids":                    1,
        "provider_category":               1,
        "provider_info":                   1,
        "arrival_date_time":               1,
        "adjust_time":                     1,
        "adjusted_time":                   1,
        "length":                          1,
        "provider_length":                 1,
        "customer_info":                   1,
        "industry_id":                     1,
        "form_id":                         1,
        "service_category":                1,
        "base_frequency_id":               1,
        "address_id":                      1,
        "location_type":                   1,
        "base_location_id":                1,
        "zipcode":                         1,
        "frequency_repeat_slug":           1,
        "arrival_time":                    1,
        "day":                             1,
        "spot_type":                       1,
        "arrival_window":                  1,
        "arrival_date":                    1,
        "location_booking_date_timestamp": 1,
        "address":                         1,
        "end_date_timestamp":              1,
        "is_visible":                      1,
        "booking_date":                    1,
        "created_on":                      1,
        "is_first":                        1}},
    {"$lookup": bson.M{
        "localField":   "address_id",
        "from":         config.AddressesCollection,
        "foreignField": "_id",
        "as":           "address"}},
    {"$unwind": bson.M{
        "path":                       "$address",
        "preserveNullAndEmptyArrays": true},
    },
    {"$addFields": bson.M{"full_address": bson.M{"$toLower": bson.M{"$concat": []interface{}{"$address.apt", " ", "$address.address"}}}}},
    {"$match": query},
    {"$sort": sort}})
err = pipe.All(&result)
return result, err
```

If I change my mongodb settings to  `db.adminCommand({  setDefaultRWConcern: 1,  defaultReadConcern: { level : "majority" },  defaultWriteConcern: {}})` it works fine.  Can anyone explain why it is not working with the previously setted configurations and how it can be resolved.

Comment: what server version?

Comment: ubuntu version 22.04 and mongoDb version- 4.4.19

Comment: this is strange, `OP_GET_MORE` is a legacy wire protocol that should not be used for 4.4 server AFAIK.

Comment: try upgrading to the latest go driver